# Client Validation for Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, visual-studio-2013

Goal:
*When you press the submit button a client validation should be executed inside of a textbox.

*If okey, go the the actionresult.
Otherwise, show a popup message with statement "max 10 letter" with a OK button.

The criteria is that max 10 letters.

Problem:
I don't know how to do it

Info:
*I'm using VS2013 with ASP.net mvc, jQuery, javascript
*No server validation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="return validate();"
Form is submitted only if validate() returns true

Comment: *No server validation*  I hope this is a homework exercise, because otherwise you're breaking one of the cardinal rules of web development... client side validation is optional, server side validation is mandatory

Comment: MVC does not come into play at client side. You simply use on click/submit of input field and validate ur input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="target">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="txtname" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and Js

```
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var getText=$('#txtname').val().trim();
    var len=getText.length;
    if(len > 10){
           alert('max 10 size');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

check the length on form submit.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/q3hzp6p9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use data annotations with razor syntax to do such validations. No Separate code need to be written.Refer following example

```
 public class TestClass
{
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 10)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Supply Type")]        
    [Required]
    public int SupplyType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Activation Date")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
}
```

In View write as following

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CO2Config", FormMethod.Post)
 {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  //your code
}
```

Comment: where is the javascript validation code? OP needs client side validation syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 function form_validate(){
  var name= document.getElementById("name");
  if(name=="")
  {
   alert("Name is required !!");
   return false;
  }
  if(name.length>10)
  {
   alert("Name is not more than 10 character !!");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
 <script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form onsubmit="return form_validate();">
 First name: <input id="name" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you are calling onclick on textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

No Separate javascript code is required, In class definition using data annotation define what validation need to be done and in view simply bind the control to that Model.@Html.ValidationSummary(true) syntax will make sure the validations are fulfilled.

Comment: I still need a popup to display error message for popup.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link.This will clarify how to use data-annotations
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/160184/Basic-Data-Validation-Using-Data-Annotations-ASP-N

Comment: I still need a popup to display error message for popup.